# Return a vector with all df$var used in an R script

Tags: r, regex

I needed to return a vector with all variables and associated dataframes called in an R script (in the format df$var). This is to be implemented in R

Here's the way I did it:

```
library(stringi)
a <- readLines('script.R') #read script of interest. For reproducibility, you can use one of your own
b <- paste(a, collapse = " ") #collapse vector into a string
df_vars <- unique(unlist(stri_extract_all_regex(b, "[A-Za-z]*\\$[A-Za-z_.0-9]*"))) #search for sub-string elements that include alpha-numeric (ect.), separated by '$'
```

Are there any better ways of doing this?

Comment: Is your code already working?

Comment: Should it be `b <- paste(a, collapse = " ")`? You don't seem to be using `a` anywhere and you're pasting `b` into `b` when it hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: probably best to adjust the first part since `[_0-9]` are illegal variable names. also, hopefully you're aware that this will not necessarily capture what you want (all `data.frame`s, and all variables called by each)

Comment: Yes, working code. Edited. @MichaelChirico good point on illegal names. What do you mean by it not necessarily capturing what I want? In the end I want all data.frames and variables called and created in the script.

Comment: `lm(age ~ height, data = DF)` will not be captured; nor will `DF[['age']]` or `DF[ , 'age']` or any number of ways besides `x$y` that variables and `data.frame`s can be used.

Comment: @MichaelChirico that’s a very good point. Using DF[ , ‘age’] is pretty common, especially with rowSums. I suppose I could run seperate searches for each of those patterns.

Comment: what is your end goal?

Comment: @MichaelChirico Similar goal to the package validateR. Checking for potential errors in each relevant variable.